# Updating Composer in Digital Ocean Ubuntu via Terminal errors

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal, composer-php, digital-ocean

I am using a mac and in the command line, I am logged into the server, and want to install composer however I get a number of issues (see below). I don't need PHP unit and so I have also tried `composer install --no-dev` but the same errors are appearing. Any idea or solution?

```
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 2.2.2 -> satisfiable by tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles[2.2.2].
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 2.2.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 2.2.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.3.0 requires tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles ^2.2.2 -> satisfiable by tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles[2.2.2].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v7.3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.3.0].
```

I also tried to install the tijsverkoyen via Sudo and receive another list of issues

```
Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit 8.5.x-dev requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 8.5.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 8.5.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 8.5.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 8.5.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ^8.5 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[8.5.0, 8.5.1, 8.5.2, 8.5.3, 8.5.x-dev].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says you're missing the PHP extension `ext-dom`.

You'll need to install it by running `sudo apt install php-xml`.